# How to set QOS in CycloneDDS C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-distribution-service, qos

I am using [CycloneDDS](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds) [C++ version](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx),

trying to set following QOS to the writer DDS_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL, DDS_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL, DDS_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE

I am trying to set Qos to data writer, in dds publisher

```
dds::domain::DomainParticipant local_participant(domain::default_id());
dds::pub::Publisher local_publisher(local_participant);
dds::topic::Topic<DDSData::myData> topicMyData(local_participant, "DDS");

dds::pub::qos::DataWriterQos  QosW( dds_history_kind(DDS_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL), 
                                        dds_durability_kind(DDS_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL), 
                                        dds_reliability_kind(DDS_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE));

m_ReplyDataWriter = std::make_shared < dds::pub::DataWriter<DDSData::myData>>(local_publisher, topicMyData, QosW, NULL, ::dds::core::status::StatusMask::none());
```

DataWriter constructor with Qos

```
DataWriter(const dds::pub::Publisher& pub,
           const ::dds::topic::Topic<T>& topic,
           const dds::pub::qos::DataWriterQos& qos,
           dds::pub::DataWriterListener<T>* listener = NULL,
           const dds::core::status::StatusMask& mask = ::dds::core::status::StatusMask::none());
```

it does not work what I am I missing here?

```
Error   C2664'dds::pub::DataWriter<DDSData::myData,dds::pub::detail::DataWriter>::DataWriter(const dds::pub::DataWriter<DDSData::myData,dds::pub::detail::DataWriter> &)': cannot convert argument 3 from '_Ty' to 'const dds::pub::qos::DataWriterQos &'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this out](https://github.com/ADLINK-IST/opensplice/blob/master/src/api/dcps/isocpp2/include/org/SNIPPETS.md#creating-a-datawriter-with-your-own-qos)

Error is because QoS is not set properly you can try below code,

Creating a DataWriter with your own QoS

```
dds::domain::DomainParticipant local_participant(domain::default_id());
dds::pub::Publisher local_publisher(local_participant);
dds::topic::Topic<DDSData::myData> topicMyData(local_participant, "DDS");       

dds::pub::qos::DataWriterQos dwqos = topicMyData.qos();

dwqos << dds_history_kind(DDS_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL) 
      << dds_durability_kind(DDS_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL) 
      << dds_reliability_kind(DDS_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE);

dds::pub::DataWriter<Foo::Type> writer2(local_publisher, topicMyData, dwqos);

//m_ReplyDataWriter = std::make_shared < dds::pub::DataWriter<DDSData::myData>>(local_publisher, topicMyData, dwqos, NULL, ::dds::core::status::StatusMask::none());
```